# JQuery Highlight Active Textbox

Tags: jquery

I created a Fiddle that highlights an active textbox. It works on JSFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/FingersCrossedErie/kgbhe2j5/

However, it does not work on my webpage. Am I missing something?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('input[type="text"]').focus(function () {
            $(this).addClass("focus");
        });

        $('input[type="text"]').blur(function () {
            $(this).removeClass("focus");
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        .focus {
    border: 2px solid #AA88FF;
    background-color: #FFEEAA;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <label>Name:</label>
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Age:</label>
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Phone:</label>
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you happen to be using Wordpress, there is a reason why with that?

Comment: No I am not using Wordpress. It is on my local machine. I have used other JQuery Scripts locally and they worked fine.

Comment: See my answer and try that, may work :)

Comment: Thank you  that worked. I did not think of that.

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct by ticking the tick next to it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the document ready function, it may be calling before DOM is ready.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//Rest of code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

            $('input[type="text"]').focus(function () {
                $(this).addClass("focus");
            });

            $('input[type="text"]').blur(function () {
                $(this).removeClass("focus");
            });

    });
```